# How do I use a file from only one of two directories when writing a generic make target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

I'm trying to do something akin to this:

```
obj/32/%.o: src/all/%.c src/$(ARCH)/%.c
        @mkdir -p obj/32 || true
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -m32 -c $< -o $@
        objcopy --strip-unneeded $@
```

I would expect this to check if `src/all/<file>.c` exists, and if it doesn't, use `src/$(ARCH)/<file>.c` instead.

However, it doesn't work. It tries to make a target called `obj/32/%.o` with the dependencies `src/all/%.c` and `src/$(ARCH)/%.c`.

How do I do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would expect this to check if `src/all/<file>.c` exists, and if it doesn't, use `src/$(ARCH)/<file>.c` instead.

In this case one option is to create a symlink to one of these files:

```
src/<file>.c : # no dependencies
    test -f src/all/<file>.c && ln -fs src/all/<file>.c $@ || ln -fs src/$(ARCH)/<file>.c $@
```

And then use that symlink instead:

```
obj/32/%.o : src/<file>.c | obj/32
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -m32 -c -o $@ $<
    objcopy --strip-unneeded $@

obj/32 :
    mkdir -p $@ || true
```

In the above it uses order-only dependency on the directory, so that the directory is a regular make target.

---

Alternatively, use [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search):

```
vpath %.c src/all
vpath %.c src/$(ARCH)

obj/32/%.o: %.c
        @mkdir -p obj/32 || true
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -m32 -c $< -o $@
        objcopy --strip-unneeded $@
```

---

There may be errors in the above, as I cannot test it, but you should get the idea.

Comment: I don't want to have to do this on each individual file.

Comment: @JL2210 Added another option for you.